# How to change order status of Pending to Payment Review on homologation environment?

Tags: magento2, admin, orders, sales-order, order-status

Hi i'm new at magento 2 and i want to change an order status of Pending to Payment Received, but i'm in homologation environment using sample data to test my store, so I still don't have a functional payment method.

Maybe the answer could be on this place that says "*Automatically Invoice All Items option becomes available in the **configuration***". But which "configuration" ? where ?

[image: picture]

Link where i got the image.
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/sales/order-status-custom.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that it's possible to get this "Payment Review" status on homologation environment, but i managed to change the status to "Complete". First we need to subimit an invoice and after submit a shipment. Did this, the status will be "Complete" on the homologation environment.